# AFNetworking 2: передача параметров с русскоязычными словами

Tags: objective-c, ios, iphone, ios7

На вьюхе есть поле для редактирования имени (например). Пользователь может ввести имя как при английской раскладке, так и при русскоязычной. Естественно, AFNetworking 2 крашится с ошибкой о неправильных передаваемых параметрах (при наличии в передаваемых параметрах русскоязычных слов).

Сам по себе сервер требует передавать данные в кодировке UTF8. Как правильно конвертировать всю URL строку в UTF8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (NSString *)urlEncode:(NSString *)str {
    return (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef)str, NULL, CFSTR("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте `-[NSString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:]`.